# Show Time Picker in 12 Hour Format with ng-pick-date-time

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am using the owl date time picker dialog and have provided the momentjs  provider to get the format i want displayed in the input field. But can i display the picker it self in 12 hour format, That is showing the selection of AM and PM as well next to the time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the `hour12Timer` option to `true` on your owl date time  picker, according to the documentation here:

[Documentation, select 'API'](https://daniel-projects.firebaseapp.com/owlng/date-time-picker)

Comment: totally missed this documentation.

Answer (score 2):

in owl-date time component use  [hour12Timer] = "'true'" as string value.
example

```
 <input  name="mydate" [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt4" [owlDateTime]="dt4">
<owl-date-time  [pickerType]="'timer'" [hour12Timer] = "'true'" #dt4></owl-date-time>
```